# Xpathresult is undefined in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I am using some javascripts. I used

```
var xpathResults = document.evaluate(xpath, domContext, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

it is working fine in all the browser except IE11.
 It is showing error: '`XPathResult is undefined`'. And yes I used `wgxpath.install.js` script before that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you call `wgxpath.install();` ? it's worked for me

Answer (score 6):

Internet Explorer does not support XPATH.

I'd suggest using CSS selectors instead of XPath if you want it to work with IE11.

If you are dead-set on using XPath, I'd suggest using an XPath javascript library (like http://code.google.com/p/wicked-good-xpath/)

Sorry for the trouble. Support for XPath in IE is currently in development.

If you are curious what we have planned for IE-Next, visit http://status.modern.ie/

Comment: I'm just curious- I'm using SharePoint 2013 and am getting this issue form an out of the box plugin (Visio Viewer) in IE 11...is there some kind of left hand/right hand communication breakdown here?

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue. Put following code in your HTML head section and try it.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,chrome=1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem.Add following code will be useful.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">
```

Note:`IE=5`,NOT OTHERS.